# .htaccess rewrite rule get to slash based

Tags: .htaccess

I'm writing a website on custom MVC. I have URLs like this:

```
http://myweb.com/goods/?id=12&size2
```

Could you please help me out with rewrite rules to get a URL like this:

`http://myweb.com/goods/id12/size2`

Comment: You didn't try anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Rule in /.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /goods/?id=$1&size=$2 [NC,L]
```

This will internally redirect

- /2/12

to

- /goods/?id=2&size=12